# Infineon DAVE v4.2.2. XMC1200 Boot Kit 4-Channel DMX Issue

Tags: microcontroller, led, dmx

I am using Infineon Dave v4.2.2. to program the XMC1200 boot kit with colour LED card to read a DMX input signal using a rotary dial.

For those that don' know, Dave uses a simple UI with "apps" that will auto-generate code for you. I have successfully worked through Infineon's example for a 3-channel RGB LED with DMX control, found here:

[Infineon DMX512 App Overview](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-Application_Lighting_Digital_Multiplex_(DMX512)_Receiving_Device-TR-v02_00-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d4625696ed76015698fbfb177fdb)

[XMC1200 CPU Card User Manual](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Board_Users_Manual_XMC1200_CPU_Card_R1.pdf?fileId=db3a30433dd42dcf013dd45583bb0052)

[Color Card User Manual](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Board_Users_Manual_Colour_LED_Card_R1.pdf?fileId=db3a30433dd42dcf013dd456db4a0056)

---

main.c code from 3 RGB Lamps Example using PDM_DIMMED_LED_LAMP APPs

```
#include <DAVE.h>                 //Declarations from DAVE Code Generation (includes SFR declaration)

#define LINEAR_WALK_PRESCALER 0x2AC // prescaler value for walk time of 7s
#define DIM_DIV 0x64 // dimdiv value for dimming transition of 7s
#define DIM_PS  0xDB // dimclk_ps value

void OneSecTick(void);

/**

 * @brief main() - Application entry point
 *
 * <b>Details of function</b><br>
 * This routine is the application entry point. It is invoked by the device startup code. It is responsible for
 * invoking the APP initialization dispatcher routine - DAVE_Init() and hosting the place-holder for user application
 * code.
 */

int main(void)
{
  DAVE_STATUS_t status;
  uint32_t TimerId;

  status = DAVE_Init();           /* Initialization of DAVE APPs  */

  if(status == DAVE_STATUS_FAILURE)
  {
    /* Placeholder for error handler code. The while loop below can be replaced with an user error handler. */
    XMC_DEBUG("DAVE APPs initialization failed\n");

    while(1U)
    {

    }
  }

  TimerId = SYSTIMER_CreateTimer(1000000, SYSTIMER_MODE_PERIODIC, (SYSTIMER_CALLBACK_t) OneSecTick, NULL);
  SYSTIMER_StartTimer(TimerId);

  /* Placeholder for user application code. The while loop below can be replaced with user application code. */
  while(1U)
  {

  }
}

void OneSecTick(void)
{
  static uint8_t step = 0;

  if (++step==1) {
    /* Change Slowly to Red */
    RGB_LAMP_1_config.led_intensity[0] = 4095;
    RGB_LAMP_1_config.led_intensity[1] = 0;
    RGB_LAMP_1_config.led_intensity[2] = 0;
    PDM_DIMMED_LED_LAMP_SetColorAdv(&RGB_LAMP_1, LINEAR_WALK_PRESCALER);

    /* Change Slowly to Green */
    RGB_LAMP_2_config.led_intensity[0] = 0;
    RGB_LAMP_2_config.led_intensity[1] = 4095;
    RGB_LAMP_2_config.led_intensity[2] = 0;
    PDM_DIMMED_LED_LAMP_SetColorAdv(&RGB_LAMP_2, LINEAR_WALK_PRESCALER);

    /* Change Slowly to Blue */
    RGB_LAMP_3_config.led_intensity[0] = 0;
    RGB_LAMP_3_config.led_intensity[1] = 0;
    RGB_LAMP_3_config.led_intensity[2] = 4095;
    PDM_DIMMED_LED_LAMP_SetColorAdv(&RGB_LAMP_3, LINEAR_WALK_PRESCALER);
  }
  else if (step==9) {
    /* Change Slowly to Green */
    RGB_LAMP_1_config.led_intensity[0] = 0;
    RGB_LAMP_1_config.led_intensity[1] = 4095;
    RGB_LAMP_1_config.led_intensity[2] = 0;
    PDM_DIMMED_LED_LAMP_SetColorAdv(&RGB_LAMP_1, LINEAR_WALK_PRESCALER);

    /* Change Slowly to Blue */
    RGB_LAMP_2_config.led_intensity[0] = 0;
    RGB_LAMP_2_config.led_intensity[1] = 0;
    RGB_LAMP_2_config.led_intensity[2] = 4095;
    PDM_DIMMED_LED_LAMP_SetColorAdv(&RGB_LAMP_2, LINEAR_WALK_PRESCALER);

    /* Change Slowly to White */
    RGB_LAMP_3_config.led_intensity[0] = 1365;
    RGB_LAMP_3_config.led_intensity[1] = 1365;
    RGB_LAMP_3_config.led_intensity[2] = 1365;
    PDM_DIMMED_LED_LAMP_SetColorAdv(&RGB_LAMP_3, LINEAR_WALK_PRESCALER);
  }
  else if (step==17) {
    /* Change Slowly to Blue */
    RGB_LAMP_1_config.led_intensity[0] = 0;
    RGB_LAMP_1_config.led_intensity[1] = 0;
    RGB_LAMP_1_config.led_intensity[2] = 4095;
    PDM_DIMMED_LED_LAMP_SetColorAdv(&RGB_LAMP_1, LINEAR_WALK_PRESCALER);

    /* Change Slowly to White */
    RGB_LAMP_2_config.led_intensity[0] = 1365;
    RGB_LAMP_2_config.led_intensity[1] = 1365;
    RGB_LAMP_2_config.led_intensity[2] = 1365;
    PDM_DIMMED_LED_LAMP_SetColorAdv(&RGB_LAMP_2, LINEAR_WALK_PRESCALER);

    /* Dim Down Slowly to 0% */
    RGB_LAMP_3_config.dim_level = 0;
    PDM_DIMMED_LED_LAMP_SetDimLevelExponentialAdv(&RGB_LAMP_3, DIM_DIV, DIM_PS);
  }
  else if (step==25) {
    /* Change Slowly to White */
    RGB_LAMP_1_config.led_intensity[0] = 1365;
    RGB_LAMP_1_config.led_intensity[1] = 1365;
    RGB_LAMP_1_config.led_intensity[2] = 1365;
    PDM_DIMMED_LED_LAMP_SetColorAdv(&RGB_LAMP_1, LINEAR_WALK_PRESCALER);

    /* Dim Down Slowly to 0% */
    RGB_LAMP_2_config.dim_level = 0;
    PDM_DIMMED_LED_LAMP_SetDimLevelExponentialAdv(&RGB_LAMP_2, DIM_DIV, DIM_PS);

    /* Dim Up Slowly to 25% */
    RGB_LAMP_3_config.dim_level = 1024;
    PDM_DIMMED_LED_LAMP_SetDimLevelExponentialAdv(&RGB_LAMP_3, DIM_DIV, DIM_PS);
  }
  else if (step==33) {
    /* Dim Down Slowly to 0% */
    RGB_LAMP_1_config.dim_level = 0;
    PDM_DIMMED_LED_LAMP_SetDimLevelExponentialAdv(&RGB_LAMP_1, DIM_DIV, DIM_PS);

    /* Dim Up Slowly to 25% */
    RGB_LAMP_2_config.dim_level = 1024;
    PDM_DIMMED_LED_LAMP_SetDimLevelExponentialAdv(&RGB_LAMP_2, DIM_DIV, DIM_PS);

    /* Change Slowly to Red */
    RGB_LAMP_3_config.led_intensity[0] = 4095;
    RGB_LAMP_3_config.led_intensity[1] = 0;
    RGB_LAMP_3_config.led_intensity[2] = 0;
    PDM_DIMMED_LED_LAMP_SetColorAdv(&RGB_LAMP_3, LINEAR_WALK_PRESCALER);
  }
  else if (step==40) {
    /* Dim Up Slowly to 25% */
    RGB_LAMP_1_config.dim_level = 1024;
    PDM_DIMMED_LED_LAMP_SetDimLevelExponentialAdv(&RGB_LAMP_1, DIM_DIV, DIM_PS);

    /* Change Slowly to Red */
    RGB_LAMP_2_config.led_intensity[0] = 4095;
    RGB_LAMP_2_config.led_intensity[1] = 0;
    RGB_LAMP_2_config.led_intensity[2] = 0;
    PDM_DIMMED_LED_LAMP_SetColorAdv(&RGB_LAMP_2, LINEAR_WALK_PRESCALER);

    /* Change Slowly to Green */
    RGB_LAMP_3_config.led_intensity[0] = 0;
    RGB_LAMP_3_config.led_intensity[1] = 4095;
    RGB_LAMP_3_config.led_intensity[2] = 0;
    PDM_DIMMED_LED_LAMP_SetColorAdv(&RGB_LAMP_3, LINEAR_WALK_PRESCALER);
  }
  else if (step==47) {
    step = 0;
  }
}
```

This works perfectly, but I am interested in implementing RGBW control, which will require a 4th channel.

Therefore, I assumed I would have to change the number of LEDs from 3 to 4 under the PDM_DIMMED_LAMP app, assign a pin to the new LED, update the number of relevant slots in the DMX512 app from 3 to 4, add a new line in the code to gather 8-bit data for the new LED (I am using the BLUE part on the 2nd RGB LED as a stand-in for white), and then run the code.

However, when I change the number of relevant slots from 3 to 4, all 4 channels light up but they stop responding to the dimmer.

Could this be a dimmer issue?

If anyone has any suggestions as to why this might be happening, it would be much appreciated.

```
    Copyright (c) 2016, Infineon Technologies AG                                 **
 All rights reserved.                                                         **
                                                                              **
 Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without           **
 modification,are permitted provided that the following conditions are met:   **
                                                                              **
 *Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright notice,      **
 this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.                        **
 *Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright notice,   **
 this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the documentation    **
 and/or other materials provided with the distribution.                       **
 *Neither the name of the copyright holders nor the names of its contributors **
 may be used to endorse or promote products derived from this software without**
 specific prior written permission.                                           **
                                                                              **
 THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS "AS IS"  **
 AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE    **
 IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE   **
 ARE  DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT HOLDER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE   **
 LIABLE  FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR         **
 CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF         **
 SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR  SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS    **
 INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN      **
 CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY,OR TORT (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE)       **
 ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE   **
 POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.                                                  **
                                                                              **
 To improve the quality of the software, users are encouraged to share        **
 modifications, enhancements or bug fixes with Infineon Technologies AG       **
 dave@infineon.com).                                                          **
                                                                              **
********************************************************************************
**                                                                            **
**                                                                            **
** PLATFORM : Infineon XMC1000 Series                                         **
**                                                                            **
** AUTHOR : Application Engineering Team                                      **
**                                                                            **
**                                                                            **
** version 1 (first version)                                                  **
** version 2 (migration to DAVE v4)                                           **
** MODIFICATION DATE : June, 17, 2016                                         **
**                                                                            **
*******************************************************************************/
#include <DAVE.h>                 //Declarations from DAVE Code Generation (includes SFR declaration)

/**

 * @brief main() - Application entry point
 *
 * <b>Details of function</b><br>
 * This routine is the application entry point. It is invoked by the device startup code. It is responsible for
 * invoking the APP initialization dispatcher routine - DAVE_Init() and hosting the place-holder for user application
 * code.
 */

int main(void)
{
  DAVE_STATUS_t status;

  status = DAVE_Init();           /* Initialization of DAVE APPs  */

  if(status == DAVE_STATUS_FAILURE)
  {
    /* Placeholder for error handler code. The while loop below can be replaced with an user error handler. */
    XMC_DEBUG("DAVE APPs initialization failed\n");

    while(1U)
    {

    }
  }

  /* initialize global dimming level to 100% */
  XMC_BCCU_SetGlobalDimmingLevel(BCCU0, 4095U);

  /* Placeholder for user application code. The while loop below can be replaced with user application code. */
  while(1U)
  {

  }
}

void DMX512_RD_UserCallBack(void)
{
  RGB_LAMP.config->led_intensity[0] = DMX512_RD_0_rx_array[0] << 4U; // 8-bit information for Red color
  RGB_LAMP.config->led_intensity[1] = DMX512_RD_0_rx_array[1] << 4U; // 8-bit information for Green color
  RGB_LAMP.config->led_intensity[2] = DMX512_RD_0_rx_array[2] << 4U; // 8-bit information for Blue color
  PDM_DIMMED_LED_LAMP_SetColor(&RGB_LAMP);
}
```

This is the code generated in the DMX512 infineon example, available from the website, for the 3-channel RGB LED w/DMX512 control (link no. 1 above).

[image]

This is a screenshot from the UI of the DMX512 app

Its probably worth noting I have a DMX dimmer, as well as the XMC1200 boot kit, which is essential for this project to work.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way to use one RGB and the blue of another is to use the white app
" 4-Channel White LED Lamp Example using XMC LibEN"

This will map RG and B of RGB_LAMP_2 and blue or RGB_LAMP_2 with the 4 white strings.

Notice how BCCUPUT0-4 are wired.

---

**white Board**
[image]

---

**Color Board**
  [image]

---

> I assumed I would have to change the number of LEDs from 3 to 4 under
>   the PDM_DIMMED_LAMP app, assign a pin to the new LED, update the
>   number of relevant slots in the DMX512 app from 3 to 4, add a new line
>   in the code to gather 8-bit data for the new LED

I would not have changed the number of LEDs from 3 to 4.

I would just use `RGB_LAMP_2_config.led_intensity[0]` as the "white" LED.

> when I change the number of relevant slots from 3 to 4, all 4 channels
>   light up but they stop responding to the dimmer.

Need you to be more specific about "slot".
You changed what in which file?

---

You can't just change the dimensions on `RGB_LAMP_1_config.led_intensity` from 3 to 4.
You must then associate  `RGB_LAMP_1_config.led_intensity[3]` to the CPU I/O pin.
And disassociate `RGB_LAMP_2_config.led_intensity[0]` from that CPU pin.

---

It will not be easy to create `RGB_LAMP_1_config.led_intensity[3]`

The configuration spans across a number of files.

The `no_of_leds_used` is used to configure all 3 RGB LEDs.

In file *\PDM_DIMMED_LED_LAMP_DIRECT_PDM_3RGB_EXAMPLE_XMC12\Dave\Generated\PDM_DIMMED_LED_LAMP\pdm_dimmed_led_lamp.c*

```
 for (count = 0U; count < handle->no_of_leds_used; count++)
```

Then the gpio pins used are configured as

```
const PDM_DIMMED_LED_LAMP_GPIO_COMPOUT_CONFIG_t const *gpio_config_out[9];
const PDM_DIMMED_LED_LAMP_GPIO_CCUIN_CONFIG_t const *gpio_config_in[9];
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for your comprehensive answer.

The "slots" I am referring to are in the DMX512_RD app.

Since this is for an RGBW application, using DMX512 protocol to allow the user to specify the colour of the LEDs, I cannot map two colours to the same channel unfortunately, it needs to control 4 separate channels of LEDs.

Admittedly, I am not completely sure what I am doing with the slots, I will look further into it.

I can't post pictures in the comments so I will post screenshots of all relevant information in the original question.